# Problems with svg2Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, svg

I want to use the  `svg2tikz` to export figures to tikz.
I have installed this extension on inkscape correctly.
When I convert the following image, a problem occur:

[image]

When I see the output (tikz code) generated by the extension the result is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}


\def \globalscale {1.000000}
\begin{tikzpicture}[y=1cm, x=1cm, yscale=\globalscale,xscale=\globalscale, every node/.append style={scale=\globalscale}, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]
  % Image image1 not included. Base64 still not supported;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Anyone can help me please?

Why the exportation return `% Image image1 not included. Base64 still not supported;'` ?

Comment: Is the graph a vector graphic? Can you share the `.svg` so we can check ourselves?

Comment: It is hard to say based on a screenshot, but based on the blurry text and lines, it looks like the graph is included as pixel graphic. You could export the graph as image and use `\inlcudegraphic` to add it to your latex code.

Comment: Looking through your previous questions, it looks as if you might want to read [How do you accept an answer?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852)

Comment: Perfect! This figure are not in the .svg format (only a print).